# Avoid ending up in mode from onoremap

Tags: vimscript, insert-mode, map-operator

When I'm on an empty line and press <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, nothing happens, whereas on a line with an `a`, it will go into insert mode.

E.g. I have this:

```
onoremap <silent> a :normal! Favfz
```

Whether I am on an empty line or a line where the pattern is actually present, I will always go into Insert mode

How can I emulate that behavior in my own mappings?

I don't want a solution for the above, I would be happy with

```
onoremap <silent> a <don't enter onoremap>
```

Comment: Why would you insert those operations in the first place, on an empty line? It's normal that "change to where you find an `a`" fails (when there is no `a`), so the change operation is cancelled. On an empty line, you simply hit `i` (or `S`) ..

Comment: I believe I have illustrated my intention. With the above remap <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> will enter insert mode no matter if there is a "asdfz", "abc", or nothing at all. I only want it to enter insert mode, if there is "asdfz".

Comment: I see. For your question - there are more powerful ways of defining text-objects/motions/operators, but they involve calling "real" vimscript functions. There are even plugins that build on that: https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user (the idea is that, using functions, you can achieve what you want - you can check for example if you have an `a` on your line, or your line is empty etc. and enter - or not - insert mode from your function (mapped to your keys).